# How to check if a given session ID exists in the database mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

I am generating custom session IDs using the `genid` function with `express-session` and `connect-mongo`:

```
app.use(session({
 store: new MongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: db,
  clear_interval: 60
 }),
 secret: 'someSecret',
 name: 'secret',
 genid: function(req){
   return uuid4();
 },
 resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: false,
 cookie: {
   httpOnly: true,
   sameSite: true,
   maxAge: 60*1000
 }
```

}));

Id generated by `uuid4()`, I know that it has uniqueness, but not always, I want to know 100% that there is no such ID in the database, I want to check every time this ID is generated, whether such ID already exists in the database. I dug the whole Internet, but did not find anything about how to check that a session with such an ID already exists. I would like to implement it in `genid` function, like this:

```
  genid: function(req){
      let newID = uuid4();
      //check if a session with this `newID` exists in the database
  }
```

I don't know how to access the session ring generated by `connect-mongo`. Sorry for my English. I would be grateful if someone could help! :)

Comment: I don't think connect-mongo allows you to query anything. However, it does support Mongoose so you can use that to check.

Comment: @Tyger, yes, but I do not know how to access the session model using the mongoose, when I have not created this model manually, like: `new Schema({...})`, can you help me with this? I honestly don't know what to do.

Comment: From the docs, it seems like connect-mongo stores the data in the session collection so I would look in there using compass to verify.